# Multibody Plant Point Contact Model Failing

Tags: drake

I am trying to add contact to my MultibodyPlant using

```
plant.set_contact_model(ContactModel.kPoint)
```

as well as collision tags in the urdf to a sphere and cylinder.
The urdfs look like

```
<collision>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius=".2" length="0.102" />
      </geometry>
      <drake:proximity_properties>
        <drake:mu_static value="1000"/>
        <drake:mu_dynamic value="1000"/>
      </drake:proximity_properties>
    </collision>
```

However, the trajectory obtained from direct collocation shows the sphere passing through the cylinder. I have also tried hydroelastic collision but the result was the same. Not sure why the contact is not being detected?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few layers to this question. First, I would try to confirm that you can simulate the dynamics and see the contact being respected. We normally simulate contact using MultibodyPlant set with time_step>0.0 -- to put it in discrete mode.

If you are using DirectCollocation, then you are using MultibodyPlant with time_step=0.0. I would recommend a second debugging step of making sure you are happy with *simulating* the plant with that contact using time_step=0.0.

Then we can ask about how the DirectCollocation problem is set up. Remember that in class we talk about [hybrid trajectory optimization](https://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/contact.html), because planning through contact is difficult. It might be possible to power through just using DirectCollocation taking gradients directly through contact, but I just want to make sure you're making that choice knowingly.